# Markers seem to be "cut" from the map

Tags: javascript, here-api

Using the example on the documentation i have an app that displays the route from one waypoint to another 
The problem i have is that the map chooses the zoom value such that the markers get cut off as shown in the image, this seems to be the case in the documentation as well [Routing Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html)

Is there a way to reduce the size of the marker? or some other solution to ensure that the markers are fully displayed 
[Image from my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iVTj.png)

I have tried reducing the size of the container to no avail

Here is the code if it's of any help

```
   <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div  style="height: 90%; width: 100%;"  class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="mapContainer">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you have zero control of the "extent" nor the zoom level from what you learned in the documentation? Sounds unlikely... Also you should show some source code.

Comment: No i did add the functionality for zooming in and out as well as panning but i would like the default map to display the markers fully.
I'll add the code now

Answer (score 0):

You should set the map's padding option. There are two ways to set it:

**1. add padding property when initializing the map:**

```js
// assuming defaultLayers is defined
map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: {lat: 50, lng: 20},
  zoom: 15,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
  padding: {top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50}
}),
```

**2. set padding on map's ViewPort object on the fly:**

```js
map.getViewPort().setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle example: [Zoom to set of markers](https://jsfiddle.net/8bh93e27/)

For more details see documentation for [H.Map#Options](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.Map.html#.Options) and [H.map.ViewPort#setPadding](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.ViewPort.html#setPadding)